# HTTP Basic Auth over SSL and NON-SSL (require entry just once)

Tags: http, ssl, nginx, basic-authentication

Forgive me if this has been asked already, I could not find the answer if it did exist.

We have a basic auth prompt using `nginx 1.6.0` - and when a user goes to our site at http://example.com/home - they get prompted for the basic auth using the following piece of code in our nginx vhost configuration:

```
    auth_basic "Development Realm - Proceed with caution...";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/html/auth/.auth;
```

This works great, however, as soon as the user goes to `https` (https://example.com/secure) - they are prompted for the http basic auth again.

Now, I am aware that these are two separate vhosts, and technically two separate domains. I would just like to know if there is any possible way to carry their authorization headers over to SSL?

Comment: Why not use https always?

Comment: @AlexeyTen - are you serious?

Comment: Yes. What the reason to stick with http if you already have certificate and configured ssl? Anyway, there is no way to do what you want with basic auth. See http://serverfault.com/q/253065/211028, http://serverfault.com/q/62868/211028